# How can i import AWS secrets using scala Maven Project

Tags: scala, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to fetch secret values from Aws like grant_type, client_id, and client_secret in my scala code using the maven dependencies. I found a [link](https://index.scala-lang.org/eduardohl/aws-secretsmanager/aws-secretsmanager/0.0.10?target=_2.13) in which we can connect to a region and retrieve the secret value using the below

SecretManager(Regions."regionFromAWS")
.retrieveSecretValue("SecretName")

however it returns a Task[Secret] result from which we can extract the values. but i am not sure how to extract the values.

Comment: The library uses Monix under the hood. You'll have to get familiar with it to better understand how to use `Task`.

Comment: Personal opinion: I would stick with the official AWS Java SDK though.